# html print to two/more printer

Tags: javascript

I have developed a Restaurant Order Punching software that prints Kitchen Order Ticket (KOT) & Bar Order Ticket (BOT) in one html page in two parts. But in one print click KOT part should go to kitchen printer & BOT part should go to bar printer. Printer can be more than two if some items are available at some other counters like ice cream etc. I can do it by using CSS & 'two/three/no_of_sections' but customer needs it in one click. I am stuck please help.

Bilal

Comment: This application is browser-based and this scripting is happening in JS? You won't have any control over which printer is used via JavaScript, at least I'm fairly certain that's not possible.

Comment: You might consider setting up a few web services that you call via AJAX, that do the printing using server side code.  I've worked on a lot of POS apps, and it's pretty simple to print to a receipt/order ticket via service side code.

Answer (score 3):

It is **not possible** to do this with JavaScript in just one click. For security reasons, JS is sandboxed - in this particular case, that means that JS can only be used to bring up the browser's `Print` window, and **that's it.**

Further reference: [`window.print()` @ MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.print).

---

You could, however, set up a *print proxy* like [Google Cloud Print](http://code.google.com/apis/cloudprint/).

Answer (score 1):

You can't automate this using Javascript. Why?

> Which print dialog box displays when
>   someone presses the print button in
>   their browser or the Javascript
>   window.print() method runs depends on
>   the operating system and what printers
>   are installed on the computer.

Good explanation [here](http://javascript.about.com/od/events/a/print.htm).

Note: Please don't ask "if I know the OS and what printers installed, can I do it?" ;-)